# Injecting host from HttpContext into Service layer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap, httpcontext, asp.net-web-api

I need to apply filtering by requesting host name on all database calls in my Web API service.

This filtering works like so:

1. lookup the Site to profile against based on the requesting hostname
2. Apply Site.Id on all subsequent data access calls made in the request

Essentially a global filter so so that data returned by the API service is always contained to the host.

One solution would be to pass the host name in as an argument on all my service methods like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Profiles> GetProfiles ()
{
 var host = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
 return profilesService.Get(host);
}
```

But since this is a consistent rule on all requests I would like to come up with a more elegant way to handle this so my service calls are just profileSerivce.Get();

I think I need to inject a ISiteLocator into my service layer that has either the host name or even better the Id already retrieved from the database that I can then apply. But I'm struggling with this on how and where I can reference the HttpContext to get the host name and also if it was possible to optimise this using StructureMap lifecycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I need to inject a ISiteLocator into my service layer

It seems to me you are heading into the right direction.

> I'm struggling with this on how and where I can reference the
>   HttpContext

This is really simple actually. Define the `ISiteLocator` in your business layer and define an `AspNetSiteLocator` implementation into your ASP.NET web application, preferably close to (or inside) your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx). That implementation might look like this:

```
public class AspNetSiteLocator : ISiteLocator
{
    private readonly ISiteRepository siteRepository;

    public AspNetSiteLocator(ISiteRepository siteRepository)
    {
        this.siteRepository = siteRepository;
    }

    Site ISiteLocator.GetCurrentSite()
    {
        return this.siteRepository.GetById(CurrentHostName);
    }

    private static string CurrentHostName
    {
        get
        {
           return HttpContext.Current.Request
               .ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
        }
    }
}
```

> that has either the host name or even better the Id already retrieved
>   from the database

Try to let your `ISiteLocator` return data in a way that is most convenient to the consumers of that locator. In my example I returned a `Site` entity (if you have such an entity in your domain). This is probably more convenient than the host name or the Id, since consumers possibly have to query for the site again thereselves. However, perhaps Id is the most convenient, but that's up to you to find out.

> how [...] to optimise this using StructureMap lifecycles

The implementation above doesn't have any state, so it can be registered with any lifetime; singleton for instance. However, every call to `ISiteLocator.GetCurrentSite()` will result in a new request to the `ISiteRepository`, which can cause too much overhead. In that case you probably want an implementation that stores the `Site` in a private field and always returns that instance. In that case you shoud register that implementation on a 'Per Web Request' basis (since the `SERVER_NAME` will not change during the request).

Comment: im working on implementing this and will mark as the answer once working. Something weird is happening with the injection of ISiteLocator into my DbContext and to make matters worse Web API is concealing the actual exceptions and giving me the 'does not have a default constructor'. Hopefully wont be too long..